# Plot excel bar chart from Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

How do I plot excel bar chart from Matlab?

I'm able to plot line chart.

```
e = actxserver('excel.application');
eWs = e.Workbooks;
eW = eWs.Add;
eS = eW.ActiveSheet;
e.Visible = 1;

x=(0:2:100)';y=sin(x);
eS.Range('A1:B50').Value = [x y];

eCO = eS.ChartObjects.Add(100, 30, 400, 250);
eC = eCO.Chart;
eC.SeriesCollection.NewSeries;

eC.SeriesCollection(1).Value = eS.Range('B1:B50');
eC.SeriesCollection(1).XValue = eS.Range('A1:A50');
eCO.Chart.ChartType = 1;
eCO.Chart.ChartType = 65;

eCO.Chart.HasTitle = true;
eCO.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = 'This is the title text'; % view it again

eW.Close;e.Quit;delete(e);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out just after posting it. 
We can get this by changing

`eCO.Chart.ChartType = 65;` to `eCO.Chart.ChartType = 57;`

```
e = actxserver('excel.application');
eWs = e.Workbooks;
eW = eWs.Add;
eS = eW.ActiveSheet;
e.Visible = 1;

x=(0:2:100)';y=sin(x);
eS.Range('A1:B50').Value = [x y];

eCO = eS.ChartObjects.Add(100, 30, 400, 250);
eC = eCO.Chart;
eC.SeriesCollection.NewSeries;

eC.SeriesCollection(1).Value = eS.Range('B1:B50');
eC.SeriesCollection(1).XValue = eS.Range('A1:A50');
eCO.Chart.ChartType = 1;
eCO.Chart.ChartType = 57;

eCO.Chart.HasTitle = true;
eCO.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = 'This is the title text'; % view it again

eW.Close;e.Quit;delete(e);
```

For further reference to other charts check this http://it.toolbox.com/wiki/index.php/EXCEL_Chart_Type_Enumeration